# Cannot implement Interface with different type arguments

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface, subclass

I have a generic interface `A<T>` , I have a class B that implements `A<String>`.  I've created a class `C` that extends `B` and implements `A<Number>`. 
For `C` , I get a compile error saying:

> `A cannot be inherited with different type arguments <String> and <Number>.`

Why is this not allowed?
If the answer to this is type erasure , then please explain in detail.

Sample code:

```
public interface A<T> {

}

public class B implements A<String> {

}

public class C extends B implements A<Number> {
}
```

Comment: It'd be slightly easier to answer this if you provided a skeleton of code to work with.  Nothing major, but enough to reproduce the same error you're facing.

Comment: @Raj in the question please

Comment: How can it? think about it. C already implements A<String> through B.

Comment: C already implemented A<String> through B , but it did not implement A<Number> .

Comment: C already implemented A<String> through B , but it did not implement A<Number> . If you just create a non generic class and non generic interface A, B,C ; you can do this B implements A and C extends B implements A--this is perfectly valid for non generics.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh : Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't make sense if you could, honestly.

Here's the scenario:

- `B` implements `A` and binds `A<T>` to `A<String>`.
- `C` inherits from `B` (which is *already* bound to `A<String>`), and you're trying to also implement `A<Number>`.

You can't have a type implemented both ways.

If you want to incorporate `Number` somehow into `C`, then you'll have to have the type *on* `C` and not just on `A`.

This will compile but it will look strange:

```
public class C<T> extends B implements A<String> {

}
```

Ultimately this really boils down to how your hierarchy needs to be laid out.  If you ***really*** need a relationship between `B` and `C`, then it doesn't make sense to concrete their types in this way; just have them use `T` as the generic instead.  Finally, by virtue of inheritance, you still have access to the general contract of `A` through `B` in `C`, so you do not need to implement it.

```
public interface A<T> {


}

public class B<T> implements A<T> {

}

public class C<T> extends B<T> {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Java Language Specification in §8.1.5 states the following:

> A class may not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types
> which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface
> (§9.1.2), or a subtype of a parameterization of a generic interface
> and a raw type naming that same generic interface, or a compile-time
> error occurs.
>
> **This requirement was introduced in order to support**
> **translation by type erasure** (§4.6).

It means that after erasure your class can end up with methods (if it has any) with the same signature. Refer to Angelika Langer's [site](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#Can%20a%20class%20implement%20different%20instantiations%20of%20the%20same%20parameterized%20interface?) for more details.